# Material dataTable

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to use the materials table API ,[Link to Material Table](https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props)

For example, I want to change search placeHolder form "Search" to "Recherche".

I already tried this but it dosn't work for me

```
<MaterialTable
  title=""
  columns={state.columns}
  data={state.data}
  options={{
    sorting: true,
    searchPlaceholder: "recherche"
  }}
/>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [npm package(almost last line)](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/blob/master/types/index.d.ts#L296)

```
export interface Localization {
  ...
  toolbar?: {
    ...
    searchPlaceholder?: string;
  };
}
```

So your codes should be like below;

```
<MaterialTable
  title=""
  columns={state.columns}
  data={state.data}
  options={{
    sorting: true,
  }}
  localization={{ toolbar: { searchPlaceholder: 'recherche' } }}
/>
```

Comment: This should have been accepted as an answer, this was the first correct answer

Comment: Yeah, you're right my bad, Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<MaterialTable
  title=""
  columns={state.columns}
  data={state.data}
  options={{
    sorting: true,
    filterPlaceholder: "recherche" // instead of searchPlaceholder
  }}
/>
```

or `toolbar.searchPlaceholder` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
localization={{ toolbar: { searchPlaceholder: 'Placeholder' } }}
```